# ICollection em método Put WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, collection

Tenho o método Put em um serviço Rest WebApi

```
        // PUT: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult Putpessoa(int id, pessoa pessoa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != pessoa.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            //exibição dos itens da entidade usuario
            var usuario = new usuario
            {
                id = pessoa.id,
                login = pessoa.usuario.login,
                senha = pessoa.usuario.senha,
                ativo = pessoa.usuario.ativo
            };

            db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);
            usuario.pessoa = pessoa;
            db.usuario.Add(usuario);


        db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!pessoaExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

**Classe pessoas_endereco**

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    [Table("pessoa_endereco")]
    public partial class pessoa_endereco
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public int pessoa_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string logradouro { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string numero { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string complemento { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ponto_referencia { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string cep { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string bairro { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string nome_contato { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string telefone_1 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string ramal_telefone_1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string telefone_2 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string ramal_telefone_2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string celular { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ele está funcionando, porém necessito acrescentar mais um relacionamento com outra entidade chamada pessoa_endereco, similar ao relacionamento da entidade usuário. O problema é que usuário é 1 para 1 e pessoa_endereco é 1 (pessoa) para muitos (pessoa_endereco).

```
 //relacionamento de pessoa com entidade usuario
 public virtual usuario usuario { get; set; }

 //relacionamento de pessoa com entidade pessoa_endereco
 public virtual ICollection<pessoa_endereco> pessoa_endereco { get; set; }
```

tentei fazer da mesma maneira que usuário mas não funciona:

```
var pessoa_endereco = new pessoa_endereco
{
      id = pessoa.id,
      logradouro = pessoa.pessoa_endereco.logradouro
};
```

Aparece o erro:

Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection" em "string"    WebApi

Porém se faço:

```
 var pessoa_endereco = new pessoa_endereco
    {
          id = pessoa.id,
          logradouro = 'rua teste'
    };
```

escrevendo diretamente ele funciona. Mas o que eu preciso é pegar os valores que vem do json que foi enviado para esse post.

**Resolvi o problema seguindo as instruções de Cassio, não precisei mexer nas classes(entidades) somente acrescentar no controler, no método PUT e POST o código:**

var pessoa_endereco1 = new pessoa_endereco();

```
        foreach (var pessoa_endereco in pessoa.pessoa_endereco)
        {
            pessoa_id = pessoa.id;
            logradouro = pessoa_endereco.logradouro;
            cep = pessoa_endereco.cep;
            ramal_telefone_1 = pessoa_endereco.ramal_telefone_1;
            ramal_telefone_2 = pessoa_endereco.ramal_telefone_1;

            pessoa_endereco1 = pessoa_endereco;
        };

        db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);
        pessoa_endereco1.pessoa = pessoa;
        db.pessoa_endereco.Add(pessoa_endereco1);
```

Comment: E como ta a classe pessoa_endereco?

Comment: @CassioAlves acrescentei a classe pessoas_endereco na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você deve mudar o seu relacionamento para:

**Pessoa**

```
class pessoa
{
    public pessoa() 
    {
        pessoa_endereco = new List<pessoa_endereco>();
    }

    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<pessoa_endereco> pessoa_endereco { get; set; }
}
```

**Pessoa_Endereco**

```
class pessoa_endereco
{   
    public pessoa_endereco() { }

    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string logradouro { get; set; }
    public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }

}
```

**Main**

```
public static void Main()
{

    var pessoa_endereco  = new pessoa_endereco(){
        codigo = "1",
        logradouro = "rua 1"
    };

    var pessoa2 = new pessoa
    {
        codigo = "2",
        nome = "cassio"
    };

    pessoa2.pessoa_endereco.Add(pessoa_endereco);


    foreach (var item in pessoa2.pessoa_endereco)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.logradouro);
    }
}
```

Dai na sua Função `Putpessoa` você usa a sua logica.

Link do exemplo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMUuYd

Comment: Pensei nisso também, porém, ele da um erro quando vou consultar pelo soapUi ele da erro, indicando que eu tenho que alterar o relacionamento no banco, porém, há clientes que tem mais de um endereço, alterando o relacionamento, fica 1 para 1. Tu acha que tem jeito de dar um post com esse relacionamento?

Comment: Neste link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMUuYd tem um exemplo

Comment: dessa maneira ainda não funciona porque estou usando codefirst com migrations, e ele reclama que eu tenho que dar um update-database, só que quando faço isso ele altera o relacionamento no meu banco de dados colocando 1 para 1

Comment: modifiquei a resposta, acho que agora resolve o seu problema.

Comment: fiz seguinte suas instruções e funcionou, postei a alteração na minha pergunta para caso alguém necessite. Obrigado amigo!

Comment: que bom que deu certo!